# Linux (CENTOS 6) store /etc/shadow passwords in database

Tags: linux, centos6

I have local users created for my server, though I understand that passwords are stored inside /etc/shadow file; is it possible to store it in a database as well including the records of previous passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

There is a system called NSS, that manages the databases of users, groups, etc. The file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (it has a man page). It allows letting the system know where each type of data is actually stored.

Precise details of how to do what you want depend on the precise database you want to use etc, but this should give you enough to know what to look for.

Comment: Hi Shachar,

Thanks mate. I'll look that up. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: # To use db, put the "db" in front of "files" for entries you want to be
# looked up first in the databases
#
# Example:
#passwd:    db files nisplus nis
#shadow:    db files nisplus nis
#group:     db files nisplus nis

passwd      db files winbind
shadow:     db files winbind
group:      db files winbind

Trying this out.

Comment: I have enabled DB in the NSSWITCH.CONF for passwd shadow and groups, tried logging in via ssh, but can't seem to figure out where is the db located in mysql. any suggestions?

Comment: The reason I didn't put in the specific changes to `nsswitch.conf` is because this is the smallest issue you have. You need to read the docs of your mysql nis connector to see how to configure them together.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm very new with Linux esp this particular thing.

Can you suggest a link for that document where i can read through about mysql and NSS configuration?

Comment: Try searching for "nss linux mysql".